# JPA map entity with array datatype

Tags: arrays, jpa, dictionary

I have a table which contains a column of type: `integer[]`

I'm trying to map my entity to this table and I've tried the following suggestion of:

```
@ElementCollection
private ArrayList<Integer> col;

public MyEntity() {
  col = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

However I get the following error:  `Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements`

Not sure how to get around this. I'm open to changing the entity's datatype, but I would prefer not to move this property into its own table/entity. Is there another solution? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but still the same issue. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The field must be of type `List<Integer>`, not `ArrayList<Integer>`.

The JPA engine must be able to use its own List implementation, used for lazy-loading, dirty checking, etc.

It's a good idea in general to [program on interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) rather than implementations, and it's a requirement to do it in JPA entities.

Comment: That's actually how I had it originally, but I got a different error. I saw in another post that it was recommended to switch to a concrete implementation of a List. Anyways, using `List` I get the following error: `ERROR: relation "myentity_col" does not exist`. Don't know why its even looking for such a relation.

Comment: Because you need a database table to store these integers. Since you didn't provide any CollectionTable annotation to specify the table name, the default name (`myentity_col`) is used

Comment: The integers are stored in the same table as the entity. Its an integer[] column datatype.

Comment: That is a non-standard way of mapping a list of integers. ElementCollection won't help. You'll need to define a custom type (if using Hibernate, don't know for other implementations).